# PayPal: alternative to ConfigManager.getInstance().load()

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to create an IPN listener by following [this example](https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-java/blob/master/adaptivepaymentssample/src/main/java/com/sample/ipn/IPNListenerServlet.java):

```
public class IPNListenerServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ConfigManager.getInstance().load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/sdk_config.properties"));
        IPNMessage  ipnlistener = new IPNMessage(request);
        boolean isIpnVerified = ipnlistener.validate();
        String transactionType = ipnlistener.getTransactionType();
        Map<String,String> map = ipnlistener.getIpnMap();

        LoggingManager.info(IPNListenerServlet.class, "******* IPN (name:value) pair : "+ map + "  " +
                "######### TransactionType : "+transactionType+"  ======== IPN verified : "+ isIpnVerified);
    }
}
```

However `ConfigManager.getInstance().load()` is deprecated and, in my project, the config file is not in the default location so, what is the right way to load the configuration file?

Comment: I'm with the same problem. Some help please!

Comment: @BrunoDeFreitasBarros: I've written a blog post http://www.alfplus.com/2013/06/paypal-ipn-odyssey-part-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution:

1. Provide an empty sdk_config.properties in the default location;
2. Load the property file manually, get the related map and pass it to the IPNMessage constructor;

More info [here](http://www.alfplus.com/2013/06/paypal-ipn-odyssey-part-2/).